# Why I'm not able to run the jQuery code in one of my pages from the project in following scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, output

I'm using PHP, jQuery, Smarty, etc. for my website.

I've one form on which there are three input text fields viz. **zip_code, city and state**. I've written jQuery code to auto-populate the city and state input text fields when user enters valid US zip code into input text field **zip_code**.

Other jQuery functionality on the form is working fine and perfect but I'm having issue only with this functionality. I created one demo page for this functionality there this zip_code functionality worked properly. But it's not working in my project.

I'm putting below the whole HTML of the page which contains the form :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Project Name</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Example of Fixed Layout with Twitter Bootstrap version 2.0 from w3resource.com">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <link href="http://localhost/project_folder/user_ui_files/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">       
    <link href="http://localhost/project_folder/user_ui_files/css/example-fixed-layout.css" rel="stylesheet">    
    <link href="http://localhost/project_folder/user_ui_files/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://localhost/project_folder/user_ui_files/css/bootstrap-modal.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://localhost/project_folder/user_ui_files/css/slippry.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://localhost/project_folder/user_ui_files/css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://localhost/project_folder/user_ui_files/css/jquery.dateLists.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <style type="text/css">

    .hideme {
      opacity:0;
    }
    @media (max-width: 979px) {
      .navbar-fixed-top.navbar-absolute {
        position: absolute;
        margin: 0;
      }
    }
    .navbar-absolute + div {
      margin-top: 58px;
    }
    #footer {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }   
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-absolute">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="brand" href="http://localhost/project_folder/index.php"><img src="http://localhost/project_folder/user_ui_files/img/logo.png"/></a>
          <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav  pull-right navbar-fixed-bottom">
              <li><a href="http://localhost/project_folder/login.php"><i class="icon-user icon-black"></i> LOGIN</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost/project_folder/register.php"><i class="icon-pencil icon-black"></i> REGISTER</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://localhost/project_folder/chk_rebate_status.php"><i class="icon-edit icon-black"></i> REBATE STATUS</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost/project_folder/contact_us.php"><i class="icon-envelope icon-black"></i> CONTACT</a></li>
                  <li><a href="storelocations.php"><i class="icon-map-marker icon-black"></i> STORE LOCATOR</a></li>
              <li>
                <form action="index.php" class="navbar-form pull-right" id="formzip" method="post">
                  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="op" id="op" value="zip_code">
                  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="form_submitted" id="form_submitted" value="yes">
                  <input style="width: 115px;" type="text" placeholder="Enter the zip code" name="zip_code" id="zip_code"  value="" > <i class="icon-zip" style="margin-top:3px;" onclick='$("#formzip").submit();'></i>
                </form>
              </li>                
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>   
    <style type="text/css">
    .list {
      width:60px;
    }

    .dateLists_container {
    }

    .dateLists_container .list {
      float:left;
    }

    .dateLists_container .day_container {
    }

    .dateLists_container .day_container .list {
      margin-right:10px;
    }

    .dateLists_container .month_container {
    }

    .dateLists_container .month_container .list {
      margin-right:10px;    
    }

    .dateLists_container .year_container {
    }

    .dateLists_container .year_container .list {
    }
    </style>
    <div class="container" style="padding-top: 140px; margin-bottom: 90px;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span12 account-container12">        
          <legend>New User? Register</legend>
          <form action="register.php" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
            <div class="row">
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="op" id="op" value="preview">
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="form_submitted" id="form_submitted" value="yes">
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="main_op" id="main_op" value="">
              <div class="col-xs-1"></div>                     
            </div>
            <div class="span6">
              <div style="float: clear;"></div>
              <fieldset>
                <!-- Form Name -->
                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="First Name">First Name<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input name="first_name" id="first_name" value="" type="text" placeholder="Enter your first name">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="Last Name">Last Name<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input name="last_name" id="last_name" value="" type="text" placeholder="Enter your last name">    
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="Street 1">Address 1<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input name="street1" id="street1" value="" type="text" placeholder="Enter the address">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="Street 2">Address 2</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input name="street2" id="street2" value="" type="text" placeholder="Enter your address">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="Zip">Zip<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input name="zip_code" id="zip_code" value="" type="text" placeholder="Enter your zip code" class="input-medium">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="City">City<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input name="city" id="city" value="" readonly="readonly" type="text" placeholder="Select your city" class="input-medium">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="State Code">State<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input name="state_code" id="state_code" value="" readonly="readonly" type="text" placeholder="Enter state code" class="input-medium">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>      
            </div>
            <div class="span5">
              <fieldset>
                <!-- Text input-->            
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="DOB">Date Of Birth<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input class="form-control date_control" type="text" name="dob" id="dob" value="">
                  </div>
                </div>              
                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="Email Id">Email Id<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input name="email" id="email" value="" type="text" placeholder="Enter your mail ID">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="num">Phone No.</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input name="phone_no" id="phone_no" value="" type="text" placeholder="Enter phone no." class="input-medium">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="Password">Password<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input name="password" id="password" value="" type="password" placeholder="Enter the Password" class="input-medium">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="Password">Confirm Password<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" value="" type="password" placeholder="Re-enter the password" class="input-medium">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Multiple Radios -->
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="radios">Mode of Payment</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <label class="radio" for="radios-0">
                    <input type="radio"   name="mode_of_payment" value="paypal">
                    PayPal
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio" for="radios-1">
                    <input type="radio"  name="mode_of_payment" value="check">
                    Check
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Text input-->
                <div id="paypal_op"  style="display:none;"  class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="email">PayPal Email Account</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="pay_pal_email" id="pay_pal_email"  value=""  placeholder="Enter email id" class="input-large">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>        
            </div>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="span2"></div>
                <div class="span5">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i> Preview</a>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->    
    <footer style="background-color:#000" id="footer">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="span3 top-buffer-footer">
            <p> &copy; 2014 PROJECT NAME</p>
            </div>
            <div align="center" class="span7 top-buffer-footer">
            <a  href="#">About Us</a> |
              <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a> |
              <a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a>
          </div>
            <div class="span2 top-buffer-footer">
            <a style="float:right"  href="#">Powered By COMPANY NAME</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>      
    </footer>    

    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster and more quicker-->
    <script src="http://localhost/project_folder/user_ui_files/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/project_folder/user_ui_files/js/slippry.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/project_folder/user_ui_files/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/project_folder/user_ui_files/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/project_folder/user_ui_files/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/project_folder/user_ui_files/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/project_folder/user_ui_files/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/project_folder/user_ui_files/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/project_folder/user_ui_files/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/project_folder/user_ui_files/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/project_folder/user_ui_files/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/project_folder/user_ui_files/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/project_folder/user_ui_files/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/project_folder/user_ui_files/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://localhost/project_folder/user_ui_files/js/bootstrap-modalmanager.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/project_folder/user_ui_files/js/jquery.dateLists.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/project_folder/user_ui_files/js/custom/common.js"></script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

The jQuery code to run this zip code functionality is written into file **common.js** which is included at last of this page.

Following is the code from the file **common.js**:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
  $(window).scroll( function(){
    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.hideme').each( function(i) {

      var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
      var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

      /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
      if( bottom_of_window > (bottom_of_object - (bottom_of_object * 0.2)) ) {

        $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},300);

      }

    }); 
  });
  /*jQuery code for autopo-populate city and state when customer enters valid zip code*/
  $("#zip_code").keyup(function() {
    var el = $(this);

    if (el.val().length === 5) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://zip.elevenbasetwo.com",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        data: "zip=" + el.val(),
        success: function(result, success) {
          $("#city").val(result.city);
          $("#state_code").val(result.state);
        }
      });
    }
  });

  $('#dob').dateDropDowns({dateFormat:'mm-dd-yy'});    
  $("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
    if($(this).val()=="paypal") {
      $("#paypal_op").show();
    } else {
      $("#paypal_op").hide(); 
    }    
  });  
});

$(function() {
  var demo1 = $("#demo1").slippry({
    transition: 'fade',
    useCSS: true,
    speed: 1000,
    pause: $('#brand_slider_time').val() * 1000,
    auto: true,
    preload: 'visible'
  });
  $('.stop').click(function () {
    demo1.stopAuto();
  });
  $('.start').click(function () {
    demo1.startAuto();
  });
  $('.prev').click(function () {
    demo1.goToPrevSlide();
    return false;
  });
  $('.next').click(function () {
    demo1.goToNextSlide();
    return false;
  });
  $('.reset').click(function () {
    demo1.destroySlider();
    return false;
  });
  $('.reload').click(function () {
    demo1.reloadSlider();
    return false;
  });
  $('.init').click(function () {
    demo1 = $("#demo1").slippry();
    return false;
  });
});
```

I'm using jQuery v1.7.1 in my project.

I've also created a jsFiddle with only these necessary fields it's working fine. You can see the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b2sLp0zL/).

In my project I tried to debug the code, tried to put alert inside the function I wrote for zip_code. Neither the Firebug console shown me any error nor the alert got printed.

Then I tried to print the alert outside the zip_code function (i.e. on page load) it printed. The alert is not getting printed inside the function. Also I tried various other events like focus, blur, etc. instead of key up then also the alert didn't print. The Firebug console never shown me any error or warning.

Comment: You should be concentrating on what's *not working*. Your fiddle merely demonstrates what *is working*. Specifically, please elaborate more on this - *it's not working in my project*.

Comment: @Boaz:I've added the explanation about what I tried and what issues I face in my project. Is it fine or do you want anything more from me?

Comment: It's much clearer now. Have you tried checking with other browsers, like Chrome? Have you cleared your cache thoroughly? Make sure the changes you've made actually exist in the script being served to the browser.

Comment: @Boaz:In last two days I've done everything you mentioned above in your second comment. I didn't receive any error. After trying, trying and trying at last I'm asking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The markup in your post includes two `form` elements, one in what appears to be a navigation menu and another in what appears to be the main content of the page. Both these forms have an input element with the id `zip_code`.

In HTML `id` attributes are meant to be unique. For this reason, the expression `$('#zip_code')` would return only the first of the two elements with that id - the one in the navigation menu. This in turn causes the `keyup` event to not be bound to the second (and relevant) input field.

The reason it works in your fiddle is that the HTML in the fiddle does not include the navigation menu and therefore the markup includes only a single input element with the `zip_code` id.

Comment: :Perfect man, you saved my life. Detected the exact issue. Thank you so much man for your valuable help. I've accepted your answer and upvoted it too.